# Login to Apple Developer Console using curl or some other bash command

Tags: linux, bash, curl

What I am trying to solve, is how to download some files (i.e. Provisioning Profiles) from a site (i. e. [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)) as simply as possible (i. e. using curl or wget).

Questions about how to log in to a website have been asked before, but I don't know how to apply the answers to do it for Apple.

I'm having problems with the login part. Here is what I tried:

```
curl --output out.html --user someUser:somePassword "https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=someAutoGeneratedKey"
```

and this:

```
curl --output out.html --data "appleId=someUser&accountpassword=somePassword&submit=Login" "https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=someAutoGeneratedKey"
```

Both of the commands fail to log me in.

Any pointers in how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it working.

For login (the key here is to use the --location flag and save the cookies):

```
curl --location --data "appIdKey=someAutoGeneratedKey&appleId=someUser&accountPassword=somePassword" "https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/authenticate" --cookie-jar ./authenticate_cookie --output auth_output.html
```

For getting the list of devices in JSON format:

```
curl --data "teamId=someTeamID&includeRemovedDevices=true&includeAvailability=true&pageSize=500&pageNumber=1&sort=status%253dasc" "https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/ios/device/listDevices.action" --cookie ./authenticate_cookie --output all_devices.json
```

To get the proper links for the request I used FireFox developer tools.

Note that the links and how the call is made might change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
curl -k --user "someUser:accountpassword" "https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=someAutoGeneratedKey" --output out.html
```